# Sql: Incorrect syntax near the keyword "as"

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query. I'm not sure why it says the error in the title. I marked where is the error.

```
SELECT cmp.idcampanie,
       spt.idspot,
       spt.alias,
       perioada =
  (SELECT perioada
   FROM dbo.tf_formatperioada(spt.datainceput, spt.datasfarsit)),
       tipprogramare = tipprg.nume,
       ora =
  (SELECT ora
   FROM dbo.tf_formatora(spt.ora, 0)),
       spt.aliasex,
       durata =
  (SELECT durata
   FROM dbo.tf_formatdurata(spt.durata)),
       spt.coststandard,
       spt.cost,
       spt.nrdifuzari,
       spt.valoare
FROM dbo.campanii AS cmp CROSS apply
  (SELECT idspot, ALIAS, datainceput, datasfarsit, orafixa, tipprogramare, ora, aliasex, durata, coststandard, cost, nrdifuzari = sum(nrdifuzari), valoare = sum(valoare)
   FROM dbo.tf_costurispoturi(cmp.idgrupmedia, cmp.idcampanie, cmp.datainceput, cmp.datasfarsit, cmp.idoferta, cmp.coeficienticostduratespoturi, cmp.coeficientcost, NULL)
   WHERE idcanalmedia IS NOT NULL
   GROUP BY idspot, ALIAS, datainceput, datasfarsit, orafixa, tipprogramare, ora, aliasex, durata, coststandard, cost) AS spt
INNER JOIN dbo.tipuriprogramari AS tipprg ON tipprg.orafixa = spt.orafixa
AND tipprg.tipprogramare = spt.tipprogramare
WHERE cmp.idgrupmedia = 1
  AND cmp.datainceput <= '5.01.2014'
  AND cmp.datasfarsit >= '5.30.2014'
ORDER BY cmp.idcampanie ASC,
         spt.ALIAS ASC, spt.ora **AS spt** COMPUTE spt AS sptdtl BY idcampanie,
                                                                    idspot,
                                                                    ALIAS,
                                                                    perioada,
                                                                    tipprogramare) RELATE idcampanie TO idcampanie) AS spt
```

Comment: Whoa! What on earth does that query do?

Comment: Please trim the query down to only the offending part, include a dataset to repro the problem (possible a sql fiddle in *addition* to the question), tell us what you've tried and researched and why your solutions didn't work.

Comment: if I do that is says: Incorrect syntax new ')'

Comment: the query is from a VB written program and I have to migrate it to c#. I don't know what it does. I want to know if I've missed anything on the query because that syntax error

Comment: being likely a syntax error due to something he wrote bad, trimming it down could hide the syntax problem, unless by chance the problem's origin is clear in the "offending part" itself, and it's not obvious that it must be so.

Comment: It looks as if the issue is that you're using aliases in the ORDER BY clause. There's no need to do so, as the actual column you're sorting by is already in there.

Comment: if I remove the aliases from the order by, it gives me the same results if I execute the query before the AS SPT

Comment: Is that T-SQL came in VB6 or VB.Net?

Comment: In addition to this query being huge, it's also incomplete. You have unbalanced parentheses. If I remove everything else, I get `(())(())(())(()()())))` which has 2 more `)`s than `(`s.

Answer (score 0):

it gives error in order by

```
ORDER BY 
    cmp.idcampanie ASC,
    spt.ALIAS ASC, 
    --spt.ora **AS spt** COMPUTE spt AS sptdtl 
    BY idcampanie,
    idspot,
    ALIAS,
    perioada,
    tipprogramare
    ) 
   RELATE idcampanie TO idcampanie) AS spt
```

Except this query is not give error, see query as below.

```
 SELECT cmp.idcampanie,
       spt.idspot,
       spt.alias,
       perioada = (SELECT perioada
                   FROM   dbo.Tf_formatperioada(spt.datainceput,
                          spt.datasfarsit)),
       tipprogramare = tipprg.nume,
       ora = (SELECT ora
              FROM   dbo.Tf_formatora(spt.ora, 0)),
       spt.aliasex,
       durata = (SELECT durata
                 FROM   dbo.Tf_formatdurata(spt.durata)),
       spt.coststandard,
       spt.cost,
       spt.nrdifuzari,
       spt.valoare
FROM   dbo.campanii AS cmp
       CROSS apply (SELECT idspot,
                           alias,
                           datainceput,
                           datasfarsit,
                           orafixa,
                           tipprogramare,
                           ora,
                           aliasex,
                           durata,
                           coststandard,
                           cost,
                           nrdifuzari = Sum(nrdifuzari),
                           valoare = Sum(valoare)
                    FROM   dbo.Tf_costurispoturi(cmp.idgrupmedia,
                           cmp.idcampanie,
                           cmp.datainceput,
                                   cmp.datasfarsit, cmp.idoferta,
                           cmp.coeficienticostduratespoturi,
                                   cmp.coeficientcost,
                                   NULL)
                    WHERE  idcanalmedia IS NOT NULL
                    GROUP  BY idspot,
                              alias,
                              datainceput,
                              datasfarsit,
                              orafixa,
                              tipprogramare,
                              ora,
                              aliasex,
                              durata,
                              coststandard,
                              cost) AS spt
       INNER JOIN dbo.tipuriprogramari AS tipprg
               ON tipprg.orafixa = spt.orafixa
                  AND tipprg.tipprogramare = spt.tipprogramare
WHERE  cmp.idgrupmedia = 1
       AND cmp.datainceput <= '5.01.2014'
       AND cmp.datasfarsit >= '5.30.2014'
```

Comment: I still need to compute by those columns

Comment: yes, but what is that in order by. There is no syntax as you written and can also see above in my post.  you first change order by which is readable and understandable.. then ping me...